# Interval quasi-Newton methods?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, interval-arithmetic, bisection

I am looking to find all zeroes of a smooth function $ f \colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, $
using interval arithmetic.

The standard way to do this seems to be to use the interval Newton method

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n \cap \left ( y_n - \left ( \mathbf{J}f \right )^{-1}(x_n) f(y_n) \right ), $$

where $ y_n \in x_n $ (usually the midpoint).

This requires a way to compute and invert the interval Jacobian $\mathbf{J}f$. However, in my situation, the exact computation of the Jacobian is prohibitively expensive. **Is there a variant on the interval Newton method which does not require the computation of the Jacobian?** With normal arithmetic (instead of interval arithmetic), one has access to quasi-Newton methods such as [Broyden's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method), which estimate the inverse Jacobian as the method progresses, using function evaluations only.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "interval Jacobian" and its inverse in the 2D case and what "intervals" you are using there: balls, squares, or rectangles?

Comment: I recognize that this question is interesting in its own right, but would you add a few words about where this ability is actually needed, i.e., any underlying application. I imagine that while it is very satisfying to know a box inside of which the true value of $x_k$ exists, is it not more valuable to find a box inside of which the root exists?

Comment: I am working with rectangles, and by "interval Jacobian" (and its inverse) I mean what one gets if one computes a Jacobian (and then its inverse) by using interval arithmetic (e.g. using automatic differentiation with interval arithmetic). That is, the partial derivatives are functions from intervals to intervals. (I don't know how this is formalised.)

In my case, my problem involves Bézier curves, and the roots of the function $f$ in the OP correspond to cuspidal points at which I need an underlying path needs to be subdivided. So I want to compute all the cusp points, without missing any.

Comment: Can't you apply Broyden's method to intervals? It seems like the general idea of a low rank update to the Jacobian would still apply

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more -- it seems like you can use any non-interval root finding together with a bisection method. The derivative is just helping you guess at the next place to bisect; having it be approximate should be fine, right?